# SQL Splitting data in a column into a new table

Tags: sql, t-sql, split, ssms

I am being given data constantly in the following format:

```
Items         Instrument
-------       ---------
1|2|3         201400001
2|3           201400002
3             201400003
1|4           201400004
```

and need to output:

```
Item         Instrument
-------       ---------
1             201400001
2             201400001
3             201400001
2             201400002
3             201400002
3             201400003
1             201400004
4             201400004
```

My answer is a stored function or procedure I know, but which? further, do i write the function or procedure to accept columns from any database i have or will i need to write this on a case by case basis? essentially these are reports being turned in often and i am asked to get them into sql so the data can be analyzed further.

i hope this makes sense. thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: You'll want to create a function, not a stored procedure for splitting it.

Comment: I understand you are primarily looking for a SQL-way; but if you have an option to use SSIS, the solution can be rather simple and generic.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of all possible items, then you can do:

```
select i.itemId, t.instrument
from table t join
     items i
     on '|' + t.items + '|' like '%|'+cast(i.itemId as varchar(255))+'|%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Original Code: http://dotnetbites.com/split-strings-into-table

Modified for your case:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStringToTable]
(
     @InputString VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
     , @Delimiter CHAR(1) = ',' 
    , @Instrument char(8)
) 
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, Items VARCHAR(1000), Instrument char(8)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @XML XML 
SELECT @XML = CONVERT(XML, SQL_TEXT) 
FROM ( 
    SELECT '<root><item>' 
        + REPLACE(@InputString, @Delimiter, '</item><item>') 
        + '</item></root>' AS SQL_TEXT 
    ) dt 

INSERT INTO @RESULT(Items, Instrument) 
SELECT t.col.query('.').value('.', 'VARCHAR(1000)') AS Items , @Instrument As Instrument
FROM @XML.nodes('root/item') t(col) 
RETURN
```

END